# Is there a way to play the mafia party game online ?

Tags: online, party, werewolf

Is there a way to play the [mafia party game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_%28party_game%29) online ?

Comment: I am a new user and I cannot add an answer.

I developed a new version of Mafia online game. Unlike the ones that have existed so far, this one can actually be played in a very competitive way.

I saw other sites and there is always an entire page about what is "against the rules". Like: "you must not use messengers outside the scope of the site." Something like that might be considered as cheating.

To cheat someone should be the primary objective in the game, so this is why I created my own version.

It is still being developed. You can check it here: http://bit.ly/mafiafer2

Comment: Site moved to https://exposemafia.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have previously played on [Epic Mafia](http://www.epicmafia.com/home) (which is linked to from the Wikipedia page in the question).  They have the largest [set of player characters](http://wiki.epicmafia.com/index.php?title=Characters) I have seen, some of which makes the game extremely complicated!

Comment: Thanks tttppp. I played at Epic Mafia it is the kind of setup I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

In addition to sites dedicated to mafia like those already described, a lot of forums that have a "Forum Games" section will be open to running mafia games if they aren't already - I play mafia regularly on http://forums.xkcd.com and have seen it being run on many other forums I frequent.

Comment: I only recently started playing mafia/werewolf on a football forum. Great great fun! I think I'd be terrible in a face to face game

Answer (score 2):

I'm playing right now at http://mafiacity.org the game is just amazing!

Gameplay is amazing. Probably the best mafia mmorpg game online I ever played!

Comment: This site no longer appears to exist.

Comment: This site is now some kind of communication app.

Answer (score 2):

Brainden.com is another great place to play for those just starting out in the online mafia party game world. The games are in the Forum section. [Mafiamaniac.net](http://mafiamaniac.b1.jcink.com) runs games that are a little more advanced, but the membership is very active and helpful, even providing mentors for those who haven't played before. [Here](http://mafiamaniac.b1.jcink.com/index.php?showtopic=526) is a link to a mafia introduction/guide to playing that you may find helpful if you are new(ish) to the game.

Answer (score 1):

You can play via IRC in #wolfgame on the Freenode network.

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow, I wouldn't want to play on twitter, but if you search there are whole on-line sites dedicated to the likes of werewolf/mafia, so yes.  Have fun.

This link is more useful than the wikipedia one:

http://eblong.com/zarf/werewolf.html

The links at the end are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are also Mafia games played in forums like [mafiascum.net](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CF0QFjAA&url=http://forum.mafiascum.net/&ei=E-XMT4rtLIS5hAf8rMm9Dw&usg=AFQjCNHIxL2bpC1TeNmehcQPT6gPGJgFLw).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gamerz.net/pbmserv/ hosts many games, abstract and social and otherwise, including Werewolf, via email.

Answer (score 0):

You can play Mafia live, over webcams, at [Daily Mafia](http://www.dailymafia.com).

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else mentioned it:  Mafia is, and has been, one of the top 10 [Starcraft II Arcade maps](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/) for several years.

They added a **lot** of new features over the face-to-face game, including many that wouldn't be possible in-person.  And since SC2 is so popular, it usually only takes a minute to find a full party of 12 people.

The game itself is $30 *(sometimes you can find it on sale for $10)*, but you can play Mafia [for free](https://us.battle.net/account/sc2/starter-edition/) if you play with a friend who owns the game.

Answer (score 0):

This app is probably one of the best werewolf apps I have come across.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.werewolfapps.online&hl=en_IN

Answer (score 0):

[Town of Salem](https://www.blankmediagames.com/TownOfSalem/) is another Mafia clone.

Comment: Town of Salem is no longer free as of 2020.